# How to understand the arguments of "data" and "subset" in randomForest R package?

Tags: r, random-forest

**Arguments**

- `data`: an optional data frame containing the variables in the model. By default the variables are taken from the environment which randomForestis called from
- `subset`: an index vector indicating which rows should be used.  (NOTE: If given, this argument must be named.)

My questions:

1. Why is `data` argument "optional"? If `data` is optional, where does the training data come from? And what exactly is the meaning of "By default the variables are taken from the environment which randomForestis called from"?
2. Why do we need the `subset` parameter? Let's say, we have the `iris` data set. If I want to use the first 100 rows as the training data set, I just select `training_data <- iris[1:100,]`. Why bother? What's the benefit of using `subset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is not an uncommon methodology, and certainly not unique to `randomForests`.

   ```r
   mpg <- mtcars$mpg
   disp <- mtcars$disp
   lm(mpg~disp)
   # Call:
   # lm(formula = mpg ~ disp)
   # Coefficients:
   # (Intercept)         disp  
   #    29.59985     -0.04122
   ```

   So when `lm` (in this case) is attempting to resolve the variables referenced in the formula `mpg~disp`, it looks at `data` if provided, then in the calling environment. Further example:

   ```r
   rm(mpg,disp)
   mpg2 <- mtcars$mpg
   lm(mpg2~disp)
   # Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'disp' not found
   lm(mpg2~disp, data=mtcars)
   # Call:
   # lm(formula = mpg2 ~ disp, data = mtcars)
   # Coefficients:
   # (Intercept)         disp  
   #    29.59985     -0.04122
   ```

   (Notice that `mpg2` is not in `mtcars`, so this used both methods for finding the data. I don't use this functionality, preferring the resilient step of providing all data in the call; it is not difficult to think of examples where reproducibility suffers if this is not the case.
2. Similarly, many similar functions (including `lm`) allow this `subset=` argument, so the fact that `randomForests` includes it is *consistent*. I believe it is merely a convenience argument, as the following are roughly equivalent:

   ```r
   lm(mpg~disp, data=mtcars, subset= cyl==4)

   lm(mpg~disp, data=mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4,])

   mt <- mtcars[ mtcars$cyl == 4, ]
   lm(mpg~disp, data=mt)
   ```

   The use of `subset` allows slightly simpler referencing (`cyl` versus `mtcars$cyl`), and its utility is compounded when the number of referenced variables increases (i.e., for "code golf" purposes). But this could also be done with other mechanisms such as `with`, so ... mostly personal preference.

**Edit**: as joran pointed out, `randomForest` (and others but notably *not* `lm`) can be called with either a formula, which is where you'd typically use the data argument, or by specifying the predictor/response arguments separately with the arguments `x` and `y`, as in the following examples taken from `?randomForest` (ignore the other arguments being inconsistent):

```r
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE)
iris.rrf <- randomForest(iris[-1], iris[[1]], ntree=101, proximity=TRUE, oob.prox=FALSE)
```

Comment: Also might be helpful to emphasize that `randomForsest` can be called with either a formula, which is where you'd typically use the `data` argument, or by specifying the predictor/response arguments separately with the arguments `x` and `y`.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you! Very clear answers. Now I get it.